# Rails: my ruby code breaks heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Ruby code in my view crashes my rails app on heroku. Meanwhile it works in development. I'm using HAML.

```
    = @sold
    - @sold.each do |x|
      %p lorem
```

It breaks on the **second line** `- @sold.each do |x|` regardless if @sold is equal to nil or if it has a value. Do you guys have any clue as to why?

controller:

```
  def activity
    @user = current_user 
    @selling = @user.products.where( "quantity != ?", 0 )
    @sold = @user.products.where( "quantity == ?", 0 )
  end
```

**EDIT :** Heroku logs says

```
"HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

2013-10-21T03:21:40.646768+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:           %p one
2013-10-21T03:21:40.646570+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:         - @sold.each do |x|
2013-10-21T03:21:40.646570+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:             %button Status
2013-10-21T03:21:40.646570+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:       %tbody
2013-10-21T03:21:40.646570+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:         = @sold
2013-10-21T03:21:40.646768+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/activity.html.haml:20:in `_app_views_users_activity_html_haml___1193554036748909609_69954007105480
```

Comment: What is the type of `@sold`?

Comment: Did you confirm the version of Ruby running on Heroku is the same as yours locally?

Comment: @AlainGoldman: is there any extra content above the HINT line? Please show us the 20 lines above and below this message.

Comment: ^ yes i did that by stating the version of ruby in my gemfile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
@sold = @user.products.where("quantity == ?", 0)
```

To this:

```
@sold = @user.products.where(quantity: 0)
```

I think the problem is because you're trying to use the double equals as a matcher in PostgreSQL, but it does not support that. You should use `=` if you want to check for equality there.

Comment: or use nice AR hash syntax, eg. `where(quantity: 0)`

Comment: That was it. That was a phenomenal point thanks!! I'll mark it correct after two minutes. Thanks !!!!

Comment: does it support != what if i wanted to check for items still selling would this work ?? @selling = @user.products.where("quantity != ?", 0)

Comment: @AlainGoldman: Yes, PostgreSQL understands `!=`. You might want to spend some time reviewing [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/index.html) and you really really should be developing on top of PostgreSQL if you're going to deploy on PostgreSQL (no, AR will not insulate you from the differences between databases, not even close).